# When should I use "prefer" instead of "would"?

Tags: grammar, difference

Why the sentence "Today I **prefer** to stay at home because it's snowing" is incorrect?
And why should I use "would" instead of "prefer"?

Comment: You _shouldn't_ use 'would' unless you add 'rather'! _I would rather [do something]_ means the same as _I prefer to [do something]_.  'Prefer' implies another alternative, but here it can be assumed to be going out.

Comment: Why do you want to use "would"? "Will" would be OK, as in "Today I will stay at home because it's snowing."

Comment: Please note the question form in English: Why *is* the sentence x, y or z.

Comment: @Elizabeth Hi! I hope you are fine! I upvoted your good question!

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence with *prefer* is fine. If it were replaced with *would*, the result is something very outdated. “I **would** stay home today because the weather is bad” to mean “I choose to stay home…” sounds like something out of Jane Austen.

On the other hand, combining them for, “I **would prefer** to stay home…” is completely idiomatic in today’s English.

A context in which “I **would** stay home…” is appropriate is an irrealis: “I would stay home because the weather is bad, but we’ll be entertaining an important new client, so I have to be at the office.”

Comment: Here in the UK, I don't know about elsewhere, we can use 'would' to frame a suggestion or piece of advice, so that I could say 'Today I would stay at home because it's snowing' to someone else. I don't think that's' what the OP meant though.

Comment: Yes, @MichaelHarvey, here in the US too. “I would” serves as a shorthand for “If I were yo, I would…”

Comment: Yes, the 'if I were you' can be at the end, and it can be implied without being uttered.

Answer (score 1):

Who said that the sentence with "prefer" is wrong? It's a perfectly good and clear sentence. "Prefer" means to like one option more than another. So if you "prefer to stay at home" that means you would like to stay at home rather than some alternative. The obvious alternative is to go out, so it really doesn't need to be said.

"Today I would stay at home because it is snowing" is possible but not something that a fluent speaker is likely to say. We generally use "would" when there is some uncertain condition. Like, "I would stay at home if it snowed". But "I would stay at home because it snowed"? No, because there's no uncertainty. It's already snowed.

Comment: Hi! I hope you are fine! I upvoted your good answer! I wrote an answer wrong and the community downvoted it. I edited it again! Do you like it? [1]:https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343745/while-when-i-was-in-japan-in-2018-i-went-to-many-well-know-destinations-does/343749#343749