# While/When I was in Japan in 2018, I went to many well-know destinations. - does "when" makes it sound like it is a long-term stay?

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

Background information: I traveled in Japan for a week in 2018.

Can I say:

**Example 1**

> While I was in Japan in 2018, I went to many well-know destinations.

or

**Example 2**

> When I was in Japan in 2018, I went to many well-know destinations.

Are both of them correct English?

Do both Examples mean the same thing?

Maybe in Example 2, "when" makes it sound like it is a long-term stay if the context is not clear?

Comment: 'Well-**known** destinations'. I don't think there is any difference in meaning.

Comment: You've just asked [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343743), which appears identical to me. Rather than asking questions about the correctness of specific sentences, please tell us what aspect of English you're having trouble with and let us answer that question, rather than a series of nearly identical questions.

Answer (score -1):

> - **While** I was in Japan in 2018,I went to many well-know destinations.
> - **When** I was in Japan in 2018,I went to many well-know destinations.

Those sentences are wrong.

> - **While** I was in Japan in 2018,I went to many well-known destinations.
> - **When** I was in Japan in 2018,I went to many well-known destinations.

Those sentences are correct.

They have exactly the same meaning.

I found the following in Cambridge Dictionary [1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-when-or-while):

> **"As"**,**"when"** and **"while"** are conjunctions. In some uses **"as"**,**"when"** and **"while"** can mean the same, but they can also have slightly different meanings. We use them to introduce subordinate clauses.
>
> We can use **"as"**,**"when"** and **"while"** to mean **"during the time that"**, to connect two events happening at the same time.

In your sentences the words **"while"** and **"when"** mean **"during the time that"**.The word **"when"** is used to talk about long periods of time.

Comment: Sorry, this is inaccurate. "When" is perfectly fine for describing long periods: "When I was a boy," "When I was in the army." The Cambridge page you linked has another link to [this article](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-when-or-while) which shows that both "when" and "while" are equally ok for "When I was in Japan." (Don't be confused by the bottom of the article, which talks about a specific short time in the middle of a long period.)

Comment: @AndyBonner Hi! Thank you very much for your help! You are right! I edited again my answer. Do you like it now?

Comment: They downvoted my answer. I edited again my answer. Could you please consider revising your downvotes?

Comment: @gotube Hi! I edited again my answer! Do you like it?