# Is this "Scaling up" or "Up to" ? and what does it mean?

Tags: academic-writing

Bellow is a title of a chapter of a book. Is this "Scaling up" or "Up to" ? and what does it mean?

> Experimental Analyses of Population Dynamics: **Scaling Up to the**
> **Landscape**
>
> In Chapter 6, George Batzli, Steve Harper, Yu-teh Lin, and Elizabeth
> Desy present the results of enclosure studies in which habitat quality
> is manipulated to affect food quality, predation, and competition.
> This extensive investigation demonstrates the effects of changing
> landscape structure, in the form of patch quality, on reproduction,
> survival, and movement patterns in two species of *Microtus* that differ
> behaviorally. The authors then present theoretical considerations
> regarding how population parameters across the landscape depend on
> survival and recruitment under a variety of local conditions.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Without more context, it’s not possible to provide a definitive answer. I encourage you to edit your post to add details. But your example **may** be analogous to a passage like this: “We began selling our product in small test markets. Depending on the sales and demand we see there, we hope to scale up our manufacturing to the entire intended global market.”

Comment: Thank you dear Paul Tanenbaum. So it can be a thing like "Extend" and "Generalize".

Comment: Yes, @Lambie, there is, thanks to the edits made between my comment and yours.

Comment: Aren't you reading my answer??

Comment: I just read. And thank you for your time and your scaled up answer dear @Lambie.

Comment: Ok, Mostafa. Thanks.

Comment: This extensive investigation demonstrates the effects of changing landscape structure = scaling it up.

Comment: It seems that "expanding the analysis to the landscape level (spatially)" is also logical. Looking at the study area considering the main elements of landscape (patches, corridors and matrix).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently they're conducting studies using artificial enclosures which can be manipulated to exert certain pressures on the populations living in them -- "manipulated to affect food quality, predation, and competition".  Scaling up to the landscape seems to mean in this *particular* context that they will be  *drawing extrapolations* from the artificial enclosure studies and applying them to the natural landscape, not scaling up (enlarging) the experiments themselves in order that they may be carried out "in the wild". I imagine that it would be very difficult to measure food quality, predation and competition (and their effects on reproduction, survival, and movement patterns) in a large unbounded natural habitat: special monitoring equipment would be needed and "in the wild" protocols would have to be developed.

Comment: While @Lambie's answer seems clear and good in terms of English and grammar, yours seems academic and specialized. Thank you for your time. If you are interested in reading more about this, I can email you the book.

Comment: @MostafaAhmadi Grammar is grammar. And I explained it to you and now you have changed boats in mid stream? This answer does not explain the grammar at all.

Comment: Dear @Lambie I really appreciate your answer. And I don't really see a big difference between the concept you explained and the concept TimR explained. I mentioned that your answer is clear and good. You mentioned "phrasal verb" and "prepositional phrase" and that's why I mentioned grammar. Anyway, thank you for your attention.

Comment: @Lambie: OP asked about the *meaning* in addition to the grammar. I am pointing out the meaning-in-context. You addressed the meaning in a broad, definitional manner, which is fine. Our answers are complementary. Here, they're *applying* their artificial enclosure results to the natural landscape, *theoretically*.  In this context, "scaling up" is being used to mean "deriving a theory (of reproduction, survival, and movement patterns) applicable to the natural world from the results of a limited, controlled experiment."

Answer (score 1):

The parses:
**scaling up to x**= increasing, enlarging or broadening something until it reaches x, here, the landscape.

**scale up** = phrasal verb

**to the landscape** = preposiitonal phrase

**They will broaden or enlarge** their analysis of population dynamics to fit the landscape, to conform to it.

We need to scale up our study to cover the entire population of the 1,000 residents of the village.

Comment: What do you mean by "*reaches* the landscape"?

Comment: @Lambie Hi! I upvoted your good answer! I wrote a wrong answer and the community downvoted it. I edited it again. Do you like it?                           [1]:https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343745/while-when-i-was-in-japan-in-2018-i-went-to-many-well-know-destinations-does/343749?noredirect=1#comment662954_343749